# react native. Событие закрытия приложения

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, redux, react-native

На одной из страниц разрабатываемого приложения под ios на react native есть switch компоненты. При взаимодействии с ними, состояния свичей сохраняются в хранилище redux, но при покидании страницы или выходе из приложения, нужно отправить данные состояния на сервер. Покидание страницы реализовано следующим образом:

```
props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', async() => {
  props.pushDataOnServer(data, token);
});
```

Вешаем на навигацию (StackNavigator) событие willBlur, тем самым можем отловить уход со страницы, но как быть при закрытии приложения прям со страницы редактирования свичей? Есть ли какое-нибудь событие для этого (например что-то вроде willExit, willClose)?
Или если знаете более эффективный способ, расскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

На событие, когда приложение будет скоро убито, вызывается метод `applicationWillTerminate`, но отправить данные на сервер уже не успеете.

В данном случае возможно будет оптимально сделать это на `applicationWillResignActive`, но он отрабатывает и в некоторых случаях не зависящих от действий пользователя, как например входящий звонок.